# TSQL Syntax error: missing 'if'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm making a procedure for a school project that removes a specific course from the course table if it's not in use.

According to everything I've read this is the correct setup but tere's an error on that last "END;" line that says there's a "missing 'if'"

```
Delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCourse
    (
    pCourseNumber varchar (7)
    )
BEGIN

    if NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM trackcourses WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber)
        then
        BEGIN

            DELETE 
            FROM courses
            WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber;

            DELETE
            FROM restrictors
            WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber;

            select row_count();
        END;    
    else
    BEGIN

    return 'Course could not be deleted';

    END;

END; //  <-- Syntax error: missing 'if'
```

Any thoughts and ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Weird.

Comment: Note: there is **no** `if` in SQL. Quel SQL?

Comment: Your title says `TSQL`, you've tagged `tsql` and `sql-server`, but then mentioned that you're using `MySQL` in a comment below. Please edit your question to clarify what you're using.

Comment: you tagged the question as sqlserver, tsql which microsoft SQL server not MySql... Next time use MySQL tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the word `THEN` on the same line as the `IF`, and use `END IF` instead of `BEGIN END` blocks.

```
IF <statement> THEN
...
END IF
```

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) for MySQL syntax

If you just use:

```
...
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM trackcourses WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber) THEN
    DELETE 
    FROM courses
    WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber;

    DELETE
    FROM restrictors
    WHERE courseNumber = pCourseNumber;

    select row_count();
ELSE
   RETURN 'Course could not be deleted';
END IF
...
```

It should be fine

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, thou I'm afraid if I remove the "then" I get another error saying that it's missing. I'm using MySQL workbench, maybe that helps?